Cognito Migration from one AWS account to another without changing sub
We are currently using Cognito in one AWS account and want to migrate to another account. However, when we use a Lambda trigger in the new account's user pool, a new user is created upon login, including all attributes, and the user’s sub will change since it differs between accounts. Our Cognito setup is integrated with API Gateway, and we rely on the sub to track users, which is a primary concern during migration.
While we can create a custom attribute and make it mandatory for users instead of using the sub, this raises another issue. If we implement a custom attribute, it won’t change during migration, but we still need a reliable way to track users in our MongoDB database. How can we effectively track users if we move away from using the sub
Please suggest me a simple way to migrate the cognito user pools
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context): 

    username = event['userName']
    password = event['request']['password']
    
    # Initialize Cognito clients for old and new user pools
    old_cognito_client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name='us-east-1')
    new_cognito_client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name='us-east-1')

    old_user_pool_id = 'us-east-1_hfa37RQDe'  # Dev User Pool ID

    try:
        # Authenticate against the old user pool
        response = old_cognito_client.initiate_auth(
            UserPoolId=old_user_pool_id,
            ClientId='egshhhrhhdh',  # Replace with your actual dev client ID
            AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',
            AuthParameters={
                'USERNAME': username,
                'PASSWORD': password,
            }
        )

        # Get user attributes from the old user pool
        user_attributes = {attr['Name']: attr['Value'] for attr in response['UserAttributes']}
        original_sub = user_attributes.get('sub')  # Get the original sub value

        # Create the user in the new pool (prod) with the original sub as a custom attribute
        new_cognito_client.admin_create_user(
            UserPoolId='us-east-1_ieJhg8gfefasfefesGUx',  # Prod User Pool ID
            Username=username,
            UserAttributes=[
                {
                    'Name': 'email',
                    'Value': user_attributes.get('email', '')  # Get email if exists, default to empty string
                },
                {
                    'Name': 'custom:old_sub',
                    'Value': original_sub  
                },
            ]
        )

        return {
            'userAttributes': {
                'email': user_attributes.get('email', ''),
            },
            'response': {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': 'User migrated successfully!',
            },
        }

    except Exception as e:
        # Handle exceptions
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': f'Error: {str(e)}'
        }


I kindly request that you format the code.

Done, Please check

To ensure consistent tracking of users across both new sign-ups and migrated accounts, you can introduce a custom, non-writable attribute custom:userId. This attribute provides a stable identifier that you control, avoiding reliance on the potentially changing sub attribute across user pools.
For Migrated Users: During the migration process, assign each user's existing sub value to custom:userId. This maintains continuity with their previous identifier.
For New Sign-Ups: Generate a new unique identifier for each user and store it in custom:userId when they register.
With this approach, custom:userId becomes the consistent identifier across your system, unifying user tracking for both old and new users.
Accessing custom:userId in API Gateway
In most setups, custom attributes are not included by default in API Gateway events when using IAM authorization. To work around this:
Option 1: Include the idToken: Require users to send their idToken with each request. This token contains the custom:userId attribute by default.
Option 2: Use Access Token with Pre Token Generation Trigger: If you prefer using the accessToken (e.g., for a shorter expiration period or other benefits), set up a Pre Token Generation trigger in AWS Cognito. This trigger can add the custom:userId to the accessToken, making it available in the token payload.
In your backend logic, decode the token and retrieve custom:userId for database operations and tracking purposes. Don't forget to verify the token before usage to prevent Impersonation or Privilege Escalation! This setup provides a stable and custom-controlled identifier that simplifies user management across different user pools and access flows.
